# Using mongoose full text search on sub doc and return the match sub only

Tags: node.js, mongodb, search, mongoose

Hello i have proble searching sub document by text, i have been doing it right with query $text: {$search: "string"}, but it returns the whole document include the parent

this is my collection looks like

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56b06b7fe61af1081ceea185"), 
    "accountName" : "Agnes",
    "address" : {
        "street" : "jl. A.Yani no 23", 
        "city" : "Jakarta", 
        "province" : "DKI Jakarta", 
        "country" : "indonesia", 
        "postalCode" : "61382"
    }, 
    "__v" : NumberInt(1),
    "products" : [
        {
            "title" : "Ayam goreng kremes", 
            "ingredients" : "Daging ayam, tepung terigu, bawang merah, sasa", 
            "description" : "", 
            "price" : "15000", 
            "_id" : ObjectId("56c191bd3da50ccc149717a5"), 
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-02-15T08:52:13.465+0000"), 
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-02-15T08:52:13.465+0000"), 
            "showCounter" : NumberInt(0), 
            "featured" : false
        }, 
        {
            "title" : "Sate Maranggi", 
            "ingredients" : "Daging sapi, kecap, cabai, bawang merah, bawang putih", 
            "description" : "Sate maranggi enak dan lezat", 
            "price" : "15000", 
            "_id" : ObjectId("56b06eae492acbbc1fd070e9"), 
            "pickOfTheDay" : false, 
            "sold" : NumberInt(0), 
            "featured" : true
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56c190203da50ccc149717a3"), 
    "accountName" : "acha",
    "address" : {
        "street" : "jl. Sudirman no 23", 
        "city" : "Bogor", 
        "province" : "Jawa Barat", 
        "country" : "indonesia", 
        "postalCode" : "61382"
    }, 
    "__v" : NumberInt(1)
    "products" : [
        {
            "title" : "Pecel lele", 
            "ingredients" : "Lele, bawang merah, bawang putih, sasa, ketumbar, kemiri", 
            "description" : "", 
            "price" : "15000", 
            "_id" : ObjectId("56c192aa3da50ccc149717a9"), 
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-02-15T08:56:10.716+0000"), 
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-02-15T08:56:10.716+0000"), 
            "showCounter" : NumberInt(0), 
            "featured" : false
        }
    ]
}
```

and this is my search query

```
model.find({ $text: { $search: "Sate" } }).exec(function(err, docs){
    if (err){
         res.send(err);
    }else{
         res.send(docs);
    }
```

and what i need is the sub document that matches the string "Sate" and the parent id if its possible.

maybe it looks like this

```
{
    "parentID": ObjectId("56b06b7fe61af1081ceea185"),
    "title" : "Sate Maranggi", 
    "ingredients" : "Daging sapi, kecap, cabai, bawang merah, bawang putih", 
    "description" : "Sate maranggi enak dan lezat", 
    "price" : "15000", 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56b06eae492acbbc1fd070e9"), 
    "pickOfTheDay" : false, 
    "sold" : NumberInt(0), 
    "featured" : true
}
```

Comment: It's likely you want [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) searching rather than `$text` searching. You would not be the first to confuse the purpose of the two. At least a `$regex` is capable of a [positional `$`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) match result. `$text` cannot do this, as there is no field specified for query there is no way to therefore say that it matched in the `nth` element of the array. Could be "any" field specified in the text index.

Comment: i have tried the $regex before, but the problem if user type "a", then it will return all documents that contain letter "a". so i need it to be a word check only.

Comment: Well a `$text` search would not even return that, since all text search engines use "stop words" and remove common things such as `"a","the","and","other"` and so on. All you need to do with a regex for a whole word is use word boundary charcters i.e `\ba\b` matches just `"a"` and not as part of a word. So like I said, you are thinking of the wrong thing.

Comment: yeah i think u are right, $text can not find the matches sub document position. actually what i need is, if user type "Sate Ayam" so i check that string if exists in title, ingredients, and or description fileds. and return the documents.